# Не удается корректно динамически заполнить объект в JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Если я пытаюсь создать объект section, падает скрипт в этом участке. Почему?

```
for (var i = 0; i < hrefs.length; i++) {
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://vm1.culture.ru/abramtsevo/catalog/" + hrefs[i],
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    success: function(painting) {
        var link = "http://vm1.culture.ru" + $(painting).find('.catalog-detail__image img').attr('src');
        var filename = fileName(link);
        var name = $(painting).find('h1').text();

        var [ , author] = name.split(': ');

        var values = [];
        $(painting).find('.catalog-detail__properties__row .catalog-detail__properties__row__right').each(function() {
            values.push($(this).text());
        })

        var material = values[2];
        var scale = values[5];

        var the_creation_of_information = $(painting).find('.catalog-detail__image-title').text();
        var [date] = the_creation_of_information.split('., ');;

        var museum = values[0];
        var city = values[4];
        var notation = $(painting).find('.catalog-detail__annonce__text').text();

        section: {
            link[i] = link;
            filename[i] = filename;
            name[i] = name;
            author[i] = author;
            material[i] = material;
            scale[i] = scale;
            date[i] = date;
            museum[i] = museum;
            city[i] = city;
            notation[i] = notation;
        };
    }
    });;
}
```

Хочу создать его, а потом сразу отправить на сервер как JSON.

Comment: Но его просто убрать заполнение объекта section, то все работает нормально.

Comment: _Но его просто убрать заполнение_ - не понял, что ты говоришь

Comment: в данном случае у тебя нет объекта `session`, а еще - непонятно что ты хочешь сделать, то ли отправить _еще_ один запрос, то ли вынести переменную из текущего запроса

Comment: Если из кода выше убрать "section: { переменные };", то все работает. А так, даже console.log ничего не выводит после этого участка.

Comment: Заполнить ее хотел, а потом передать на сервер.

Comment: ну так очевидно, что проблема в этом блоке. И вообще говоря это [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) а не объявление переменной

Comment: ты ее заполнить пытаешься в обработчике success - ты хочешь потом **еще** один запрос делать?

Comment: Заполнив массив, хочу его отправить на сервер, вынеся итоговую переменную из всех циклов.

Comment: у тебя в цикле идет запрос - и из него тоже вынести хочешь?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46351/discussion-between-timur-musharapov-and-grundy).

Answer (score 0):

```
var section = {
  link: [],
  filename: [],
  ................
  notation: []
};
for (var i = 0; i < hrefs.length; i++) {
  ..........
  section.link.push(link);
  section.filename.push(filename);
  ..........
  section.notation.push(notation);
}
```

Comment: что делает данный код и как он относится к вопросу?

Comment: данный код инициализирует и заполняет объект `section`. Что и просил автор

Comment: не совпадает с тем, что написано у автора

Comment: Может, это потому, что код автора не компилируется вообще и он просит указать на ошибку?

Comment: я имел ввиду логику заполнения